# Running Python Scrip from PHP

Tags: php, python

I am developing a tool that will send SMS messages, the tool is build using PHP but run Python script which accepts parameters and send SMS. My problem is the website works great and send SMS locally running XAMPP, but when I upload the website to GoDaddy nothing works, and of course I changed the path to python scripts.

This is my script from PHP side:

```
$to_phone = $modeldata['to_phone'];
$space    = ' ';
$qoute    = '"';
$suff     = '+1';
$body     = $modeldata['note'];
$Filename = 'sms.py ' ;
$path     = $Filename.$suff.$to_phone.$space.$qoute.$body.$qoute;
echo shell_exec($path)
```

which works great, keeping the same script, but changing the filename to the correct location of the Python script does not work. When I run the Python script from Godaddy it's working, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I know for sure it has to do with the python file location. Is there a different way I have to use to run Python script on Godaddy?  Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How and in which directory this script is being executed? Can you print us the $path variable and also tell us where the sms.py script should be placed?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, and to be helpful for others, this is how I fixed it, I changed the filename of path o the Virtual

$Filename = '/home/usr/virtualenv/messages/3.6/bin/python sms.py '

and it works beautifully no issues and as expected.